# Piping bash output to perl script's arguments

Tags: bash, perl, pipe

I have the following bash command:

```
find repo -name '*.c'
```

What I want to do is use the files returned as arguments to my perl script, so that it's equivalent to running:

```
perl ./myscript file1.c file2.c file3.c ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hey, I think you had `input` confused with `arguments` (`input` is generally associated with a program's `standard in` stream, which is different from its arguments). I updated your question to reflect this based on the answer you selected and your comments on the answers. Feel free to revert the changes if they were incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
find repo -name '*.c' | xargs perl ./yourscript
```

This should be the same as

```
perl ./yourscript file1.c file2.c file3.c ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Another issue just came around: my dear users use spaces in file names. How can i wrap every file name with "" before replacing the \n-s to spaces?
Sorry for being silly but i'm completely new to bash.
EDIT: found answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6041695/747412

Answer (score 1):

You can try that :

```
find repository -name '*.c' -exec perl -pe 's:\n: :g' {} +
```

The delimiter in the substitution is `:` here, no need to use `/` both in `Perl` & `sed`.

If you prefer a real `pipe` :

```
find repository -name '*.c' | xargs cat | perl -pe 's:\n: :g'
```

Comment: Added pipe version

Comment: Okay, but i have a perl script, which i have to provide input like this: ./myscript.perl -args arg file1 file2
How can i pipe my file list to this script? Sorry if the OP was not clear.